# Ocaml user-defined-types and function

Tags: types, ocaml

I have defined a type like the following:

```
type t_player = {
color : int;
coords_x : int ref;
coords_y : int ref  
}
```

And now, I would like to make a function which could be like this:

```
let create_player
    (name, color, coords_x, coords_y :
        string * int * int ref * int ref) : t_player =
    let name : t_player = {
        color = int;
        coords_x = ref 20;
        coords_y = ref 20
     };;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: One thing to try would be to type your proposed code into the OCaml top-level and see what happens :-)

Comment: Doesn't work, I have already tested and it wrote me ";; syntax error".

Comment: So then you can report the syntax error (carefully) here, and ask for advice about a specific problem :-)

Comment: Some nice manual : https://v1.realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/records.html

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed function has a syntax error. In a function definition, whenever you have `let`, it has to be followed by `in`. It is used to define local variables. Your function has `let` but does not have `in`.

Another way to think about this is to ask *why* you defined the value named `name`. Are you intending it as the result of the function, perhaps? If so you can do this by adding `in name` at the end.

Comment: Here is the code : 

let create_player ( name,color,coordx,coordy:string*int*int*int ) : t_player = 
  let name : t_player = {
    color = int;
    coords_x = ref coordy; 
    coords_y = ref coordy
  } 
;;

Where can I put the "in" ?

Comment: LIke I said, it would go at the end. You want `let v = value in expr`.

Comment: Hey, it works ! But now I can use create_player to create the player but I'm using this function like this : player_create("bob",2,32,32);; and how can I use it ? 

For example with another function : run_game(test);; don't work, I have also tried to do run_game("test");;.